# Magento 2.2 update extension clear generated folder

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Before magento 2.2 I emptied the `var/generations` folder during an upgrade of an extension or an update of magento from eg. 2.1.5 to 2.1.6

In 2.2 the `var/generations` folder is empty and replaced (I suppose) by the `generated` folder.

I always used this for upgrading (see below), but which commands to use in 2.2?

`php bin/magento maintenance:enable`

```
php bin/composer require myparcelnl/sdk "v1.3.0"
php bin/composer require myparcelnl/magento "2.3.0-beta.5"
php bin/composer update

rm -rf var/di/*; 
rm -rf pub/static/*; 
rm -rf var/generation/*; 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*;
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -j 1
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -j 1
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Yes as suggested by you the generations folder is moved in root magento as generated folder. You need to remove `generated/code` and `generated/meta` folders before any upgradation.

Comment: Before or after the composer update?

Comment: Priyank, are the commands in the answer correct then?

Comment: There are `.htaccess` files which are required when you are using apache webserver so make sure they are not removed.

Answer (score 4):

So the correct commands are then:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable

php bin/composer require myparcelnl/sdk "v1.3.0"
php bin/composer require myparcelnl/magento "2.3.0-beta.5"
php bin/composer update

rm -rf pub/static/*; 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*;
rm -rf generated/*;
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -j 1
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -j 1
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```